# Is there any way to make a button performs an action to an object without creating a new class that implements ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

Just curiosity. Is there any way to make my button performs an action on my panel without need to create a new class that extends JPanel and implements ActionListener? I mean, without doing a thing like this:

```
public class TestingSomething {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(450, 250, 200, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // JPanel
        newClass panel = new newClass();

        JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");
        // button action to panel
        button.addActionListener(panel);

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class newClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    // Action to perform
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I want to do what I asked in the question:

```
public class TestingSomething {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(450, 250, 200, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. "extends JPanel and implements ActionListener" - you don't need to that in JPanel. But you should use ActionListener.

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Button clicked");
  }
}

MyActionListener myListener = new MyActionListener();
button.addActionListener(myListener);
```

Comment: Or, using a lambda expression: `button.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("Button clicked!"));`

Comment: @MCEmperor: You are right, technically it is also possible. My reason was that in real applications one needs much more logic. Often one implements a controller or in a bigger applications a hierarchy of controllers. Then one uses instances of such controller. And my example here is a starting point for such a controller. But if the logic is really simple and does not need any reuse, then yes, your suggestion is perfect: it is short and good readable. Why not move it to a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you required the code in this way -

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestingSomething implements ActionListener{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(450, 250, 200, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");
        // button action to panel
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
                        button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);  
                        }  
        });  
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```